# Passing variables into Ember.js boundHelper

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I try to build a Handlebars view helper which should highlight a searchText in a bound field.

But I can not retrieve the bound field and the searchText at the same time. When I use only 1 paramter it works as expected.

My Helper signature is

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('marker', function(searchText,name,options) {
```

My view contains somthing like this

```
 {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="searchText" }} 
....

{{#each model}}
    {{marker ./../searchText name }}
{{/each}}
```

How can I pass both values to my helper function? and even more interesting how can I retrieve the values in the helper function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`./../` changes the scope of the helper, not a particular bound property in the helper.  A better way to look at it would be like this

```
{{marker    ./../           searchText     name }}
     ^        ^                 ^            ^
  helper    helper path     property1      property2
```

You can try this example with or without the `./../` and see how it grabs both properties from different scopes.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yuxijeko/1/edit

Your best bet would be to add an alias of `searchText` into the same scope as name and avoid changing the path.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yuxijeko/2/edit

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was a scope thing - But could not imaging that the path './../' changes the complete scope. Changed my code to introduce an item controller with an alias and now it worked! perfekt!